# What is the difference between numpy "type identifiers" and "types" within Cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

What is confusing is that if you want to create an array you use

```
chunk = np.array ( [[94.,3.],[44.,4.]], dtype=np.float64)
```

But if you want to define the type inside a `buffer` reference , you use

```
cdef func1 (np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] A):

    print A
```

Notice the difference between `np.float64` and `np.float64_t` .

**My Guesses**

I am guessing that a `type identifier` is what's created explicitly w/ the Cython C-like `typedef` syntax

```
ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t
```

But the numpy `type` is just the Python `<type 'type'>` type .

```
>>> type ( np.float64)
<type 'type'>
```

The Numpy documentation on `dtype`s doesn't help me. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 7):

in your cython code, you do:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
```

the first line import numpy module in python space, but the second line just include numpy.pxd in cython space.

you can found numpy.pxd in you cython install folder. It define float64_t as:

```
ctypedef double       npy_float64
ctypedef npy_float64    float64_t
```

Comment: Ok, so looks like most of the {float,int}{32,64}_t are C type double , extended to Python. Although I can't find mention of the types without "_t" , at least in numpy.pxd

Comment: The types without "_t" come from "import numpy", not from "cimport numpy". If this is confusing, you can do "cimport numpy as cnp" to see the difference.

Comment: Yes I just read that too, browsing through  [http://cython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html] . You can add that as an answer and I'll accept, or eventually I'll just add it.

Comment: Is it me or is the numpy.pxd unfindable? The cython github source does not seem to contain it? ah, the documentation is behind, it's here -> https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd